# Where to find such URLs that attack their visitors?

Tags: malware, websites

Where can I find websites that perform drive-by dowload attacks ?
I need such websites in order to test a software that prevents such attacks. I am in the testing phase but I do not see where I could find such websites. Thank you for any help.

Comment: You don't know how to detect the attacks that your product is preventing?

Comment: @Jeff-InventorChromeOS He obviously needs a sample of malicious websites to test his program if it detects  them.

Comment: @Jeff-InventorChromeOS so according to your logic all what I have to do is to browse all the URLs that exist on Internet and check them one by one with my software ?

Comment: Porn sites and illegal movie download sites (streaming, etc) will probably do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching for such malicious web pages is a three-step process,in which URLs are first collected, then quickly inspected with fast filters, and finally examined in depth using specialized analyzers. More precisely, one has to first collect pointers to web pages (URLs) that are live on the Internet. To collect URLs, one typically uses **web crawlers**, which are programs traversing the web in a systematic fashion. Starting from a set of initial pages, this program follows hyperlinks to find as many (different) pages as possible

https://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~vigna/publications/2012_SP_Evilseed.pdf

A **web crawler** that you may choose to use to detect malicious webpages is *Monkey Spider*

http://monkeyspider.sourceforge.net/faq.html

This is how Google locates such malicious websites

http://static.usenix.org/events/hotbots07/tech/full_papers/provos/provos.pdf

Google also publishes the **Safe Browsing API** that allows client applications to check URLs against Google's constantly-updated blacklists of suspected phishing and malware pages

https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/developers_guide_v2

You may also visit StopBadware to find out the most up to date list of malicious URLs

https://www.stopbadware.org/top-50

Comment: Thank you for all these information. But speaking about the google safe browsing API: I see lot of websites blacklisted by Google as serving malware but when I check them in a windows xp  VM on which no anti-virus/firewall is installed nothing happens (it means they are safe). What do you think about this situation ?

Comment: There could be a couple of reasons for this . Google uses the blacklist to prevent users using Google's search engine from clicking on links to flagged Websites. However, many of the Websites blacklisted by Google are actually legitimate Websites that have been hijacked to serve up malware . Another reason is many  malware developers are actively trying to foil  analysis by detecting VMEs. If malicious code detects a VME, it can shut off some of its more powerful malicious functionality so that researchers cannot observe it and devise defenses

Answer (score 1):

tearsmile here is a list of Malware samples sites some lead to .EXE sites but u will find other malware sites too.

- http://www.malwaredomainlist.com/mdl.php
- http://support.clean-mx.de/clean-mx/viruses.php
- http://support.clean-mx.de/clean-mx/phishing.php
- http://www.malwareblacklist.com/showMDL.php
- http://vxvault.siri-urz.net/ViriList.php
- http://malc0de.com/database/
- https://malwr.com/
- http://www.virusign.com/
- https://zeustracker.abuse.ch/monitor.php